# What can I do to improve this Python question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

This question [What Unicode symbols are accepted in Python 3 variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043894/what-unicode-symbols-are-accepted-in-python3-variable-names) is what is keeping me from asking more questions on Stack Overflow.

I have asked for help improving this question on this site. I cannot delete the question. I have flagged it many times, but no one will delete it. So, what can I do to improve the question so that I can ask more?

Comment: Are you getting the [“Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) message on SO?

Comment: Also, **you don't want to delete it**.

Comment: There is disagreement over exactly if a deleted question makes the ban worse or if its just that its down votes still count but either way **deleting won't help**

Comment: @RichardTingle Given that that particular questions is less than 30 days old, it would count.

Comment: Your question list looks good, the ban must be due to a series of deleted questions

Comment: Well, it has been reopened. Perhaps that has lifted your ban already? But even if it has, give your other content a good look and see if you can improve it. The further you get away from the ban, the better.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I can now ask questions again. Hopefully, everyone likes my questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This question What Unicode symbols are accepted in Python 3 variable names? is what is keeping me from asking more questions on Stack Overflow.

No, it isn't. If you are somehow question banned, there is not a single question to blame. Even if it was the question that pushed you over the threshold for getting a ban. Nor is addressing that single question the only thing you can do. What about your other questions? Can't they be improved? Some extra rep for those will certainly help. And if you can't, can't you answer some questions in the mean time?  That certainly will do no harm either.

> I cannot delete the question. I have flagged it many times, but no one will delete it.

And that's a good thing. Deleting questions (for all we know) indicates to the system that the question was a bad one. You would only end up pushing yourself further into a ban.

> what can I do to improve the question so that I can ask more?

Looking at that question I don't particularly see how it can be improved. So leave it alone. Focus on the other content.

Comment: On that particular question it seems to have been heavily upvoted in the last few hours so presumably the system won't have a problem with that one anymore

Comment: @RichardTingle Then there might be some skeletons in the closet that are causing this. Not a mod, so I can't see it. But given the desire of the OP to delete this, I wonder if that happened before. And this particular question seems familiar. Has it been brought up before?